# killing a thread which is in blocking state

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windows-phone-7, locking

I have a thread which blocks itself on some lock.Now For some condition I want to kill the thread in c#.
But the thing is that in thread.abort does not guarantees that it will kill the thread.

Comment: OK, so, is there a question you'd like to ask?

Comment: Would it not be better to fix the bug causing the deadlock?

Comment: Could you explain a bit on why the thread it waiting? BTW, there is a very clear description of when the thread will not end in the MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx

Comment: Many people seem to assume this is about a deadlock, but I see no such evidence (hence my question for clarification). Deadlock: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock

Comment: What lock?  If it's a mutex-type lock, can you change it to a semaphore-type lock, ie. one that can be signaled from another thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want a guarantee of thread death, your best option is to start a new process.

There is an excellent thread that discusses many of the possible pitfalls of thread.abort [here](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation).

Comment: I think this sentence is directly applicable: *"The approach I always recommend is dead simple. Have a volatile bool field that is visible both to your worker thread and your UI thread. If the user clicks cancel, set this flag. Meanwhile, on your worker thread, test the flag from time to time. If you see it get set, stop what you're doing."*

Comment: I agree in most cases, except the OP indicated that the thread is essentially deadlocked on a lock, in which case there would be no way for it to check the state of the flag.

Comment: You can set a maximum time to wait on the lock, and loop. Something like: `while (!getLock(waitMs)) { if (cancelled) return false; } ... `

Comment: Again, totally agree, but I suspect that there are situations where the thread could be indelibly locked (I have painful personal experience with OCR COM components that lock up tighter than a drum).

Comment: @TheNail I took your idea and did the same .thnx everyone

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to kill the thread in a deterministic way when it encounters deadlock . Right ?
Yes thread abort does not guarantee termination but  it is almost always a bad idea to use Thread.Abort. 
If there was a way to kill the thread instantaneously it can lead to bigger problems . If this thread has taken lock on some resource , is in the middle of some uncommitted transaction etc ,and the thread holding these resource is abruptly killed no other thread can work on these resources. 
Best suggestion I can give is is to fix the deadlock issue rather than masking it.